# How to retrieve data out of a private string

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

For a school project I am trying to make a binary search tree at the same time we are supposed to learn how to use 'friendship' in classes. The errors I get while compiling are: [I put comments in code where the errors originate from for clarity] (Keep in mind I am not allowed to nest Node in the BST class they are both supposed to be in separate files and classes for the sake of this programming assignment)

```
BST.cpp: In member function `void BST::insert(std::string, std::string)':
BST.cpp:11: error: `get_key' undeclared (first use this function)
BST.cpp:11: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
BST.cpp: At global scope:
BST.cpp:5: warning: unused parameter 'data'
makefile.txt:9: recipe for target `BST.o' failed
make: *** [BST.o] Error 1
```

I want to be able to access the functions in Node.cpp to be able to retrieve its private members for the sake of the binary search tree.  In BST.cpp so far I am attempting to compare a string 'key' that is passed into the 'insert' function with the string that 'xPtr' is currently pointing to.  The classes are defined as:  Node.h (directly below)

```
#ifndef NODE_H_INCLUDED
#define NODE_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class BST;
class Node
{
public:
    Node(string key, string data)
    {m_key = key; m_data = data;}
    ~Node();
    string get_key(Node *ptr); //takes in ptr to node and returns its key
    string get_data(Node *ptr); //takes in ptr to node and returns its data
    Node* get_left(Node *ptr); //takes in ptr to node and returns its left child pointer
    Node* get_right(Node *ptr); //takes in ptr to node and returns its right child pointer

private:
    string m_key;
    string m_data;
    Node *m_left;
    Node *m_right;
};


#endif // NODE_H_INCLUDED
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"

string Node::get_key(Node* ptr)
{
    return ptr->m_key;
}
string Node::get_data(Node* ptr)
{
    return ptr->m_data;
}
Node* Node::get_left(Node* ptr)
{
    return ptr->m_left;
}
Node* Node::get_right(Node* ptr)
{
    return ptr->m_right;
}
```

BST.h

```
#ifndef BST_H_INCLUDED
#define BST_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class BST
{
public:
    BST()
    {m_root = NULL;}
    ~BST();
    void insert(string key, string data);
    void find(string key);
    void remove(string key, string data);
    void print();
    friend class Node;
private:
    Node* m_root;

};

#endif // BST_H_INCLUDED
```

BST.cpp

```
#include "BST.h"
#include "Node.h"

void BST::insert(string key, string data)
{
    Node* yPtr = NULL;
    Node* xPtr = m_root;
    while(xPtr != NULL)
    {
        yPtr = xPtr;
        if(key < get_key(xPtr)) //error: 'get_key' undeclared (first use this function)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... basically you are calling non-existing function. When you use `get_key(xPtr)` inside a BST you are calling `BSD::get_key(Node*)`. You are allowed to call `Node::get_key(Node*)` but since it's not a static function (which you'd call by `Node::get_key(xPtr)`) you have to use the object:

```
if (key < xPtr->get_key(xPtr))
```

If you wanted to use it like:

```
Node::get_key(xPtr)
```

you have to mark `Node::get_key(Node*)` as `static`:

```
// Node.h
class BST;
class Node {
    string m_key;
    string m_data;
    Node *m_left;
    Node *m_right;

public:
    Node(string key, string data) :
        m_key(key),
        m_data(data)
        {}
    ~Node();

    static string get_key(Node *ptr);
    static string get_data(Node *ptr);
    static Node* get_left(Node *ptr);
    static Node* get_right(Node *ptr);
};
```

but even better would be:

```
// Node.h
class BST;
class Node {
    string m_key;
    string m_data;
    Node *m_left;
    Node *m_right;

public:
    Node(string key, string data) :
        m_key(key),
        m_data(data)
        {}
    ~Node();

    string get_key();
    string get_data();
    Node* get_left();
    Node* get_right();
};
```

and:

```
// BSD.cpp
string Node::get_key() {
    return m_key;
}
string Node::get_data() {
    return m_data;
}
Node* Node::get_left() {
    return m_left;
}
Node* Node::get_right() {
    return m_right;
}
```

Then you'd be able to use it like this:

```
void BST::insert(string key, string data)
{
    Node* yPtr = NULL;
    Node* xPtr = m_root;
    while (xPtr != NULL) {
        yPtr = xPtr;
        if (key < xPtr->get_key()) { // actual object-oriented programming

        }
    }
}
```

On a side note: don't use `using namespace std` in header to declare its usage globally - it's not a good thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

"get_key" is not a member of BST, so you cannot just call it from BST member function (even though it's a friend class).

You may call xPtr->get_key(xPtr), that should work.

But, the implementation of get_key is problematic, because it's not really using the data string of itself, but of the given xPtr parameter. to correct this you may :

1. make get_key a static method of Node (and call it using Node::get_key(xPtr))
2. change get_key to return this->data (and call it using xPtr->get_key());

good luck!